# Is there a way to subtract an amount of days from a date in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, datediff

I know about DATEDIFF(d, date1, date2), but I am not looking to subtract two dates, rather an amount of days from a date.

For example:

"2010-04-13" - 4 = "2010-04-09"

Is that possible with mySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date_sub(date,interval 4 day);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2008-01-02', 31);
```

Results in:

```
'2008-02-02'
```

To subtract, just use a negative number, or use `DATE_SUB`

Answer (score 1):

This will subtract 2 days from a date in a table, and show both dates.

```
SELECT
[Date]
,DATEADD(DAY, -2, [Date]) AS [NewDate]
FROM
[YourTable]
```

Answer (score -5):

yes. Mysql has plenty of date functions. Just google `mysql datetime functions` and you'll get the list. Date subtraction ones among them